# Intermittent Bottomless Filter Spray -- Any Suggestions?

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, troubleshooting, bottomless-portafilter

I have a Rancilio Silvia and a Breville Conical Burr Grinder.  We roast our own beans using a Behmor 1600, and typically do kinda light roasts.  Very often, regardless of the bean, roast, packing pressure, or grind size (as far as I can tell), our bottomless filter sprays coffee all over the place.  Occasionally, it works fine, but the vast majority of the time it sprays at angles that I thought were impossible (i.e. approaching 90˚ to vertical).  Has anyone had this experience and do you have any suggestions for fixing it (or even troubleshooting it)?

Comment: Seems like either very high boiler pressure or calcified portafilter. My two cents: Check pressure first. If set correctly,  thoroughly decalcify the machine and the filter.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with pre-roasted beans? I presume that there isn't any coffee grind in the sprays? Water loves to attach itself to surfaces (surface tension, capillary and intermolecular forces), there can be many reasons suppose; once the initial path is established the rest will - unfortunately - follow. Having a clean, dry filter is step 1. What kind of filter is it? Do you maybe have a picture of the (bottom side) of the filter?